# Is it possible for ssh to echo the command you send?

Tags: ssh

For example:

```
ssh me@remote "du -sh"
```

Would result in:

```
du -sh
5M  .
```

Not just the command output:

```
5M  .
```

Note: The use of du is for illustrative purposes only.

Thanks,
Zach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ssh me@remote "sh -x -c 'du -sh'"
```

Comment: That does it. Thanks a bunch.